# JavaScript: перебрать массив до определенного индекса

Tags: javascript

Уважаемые, здравствуйте!
Есть массив: [
8, 0, 3, 1, 9,
10, 6, 4, 5, 2
]

Мне нужно получить:
[
8, 0, 3, 1, 9,
10, 0, 0, 0, 0
]

После максимального числа, остальные заменить на ноль.

Вот, что есть:

```js
/*
 * В заданном массиве найти максимальный элемент. Элементы, стоящие после максимального элемента заменить нулями.
 */

// 1. Создаю масиив [0..10]
const minRange = 0
const maxRange = 10
const arrRangeNumber = []
for (i = minRange; i < maxRange +1; i++) {
  arrRangeNumber.push(i)
}

//2. Формирую массив из 10 чисел, выбранных случайным образом из интервала [0, 10].
const arrRandom = arrRangeNumber.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
const setRange = 10
const filterResult = arrRandom.slice(0, setRange)

// 3. Нахожу максимальный элемент
let maxArrNum = filterResult[0]
let maxArrIndex = filterResult[0]
for (i = 0; i < filterResult.length +1; i++) {
  if (filterResult[i] > maxArrNum) {
    maxArrNum = filterResult[i]
  }
}

const totalArr = []
for (i of filterResult) {
  //
}

console.log('Исходный массив:', filterResult)
console.log('Максимальное значение:', maxArrNum)
console.log('Индекс максимального числа:', maxArrIndex)
console.log('Результат:', totalArr)
```

Comment: А вопрос в чём?

Comment: Мне нужно получить: [ 8, 0, 3, 1, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] - не понимаю как сделать цикл.

Comment: Делать надо обычный `for` от 0 до длины массива..... вначале взять все элементы из первого массива, а если счётчик больше чем индекс самого большого числа - то вставлять 0

Comment: Вот так получилось: const array = [ 8, 0, 3, 1, 9, 10, 6, 4, 5, 2 ]
const totalArr = []
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (i < 6) {
    totalArr.push(array[i])
  } else {
    totalArr.push(0)
  }
}

Comment: неплохо, только надо не `i < 6`, а `i < XXX`, где `XXX` - индекс максимального числа в массиве.......

Comment: Да, я использовал число вместо переменной, осознано.

Comment: Полный код задачи: https://github.com/Konkin-Ivan/js-arrays/tree/main/9_task

Answer (score 2):

```js
let arr = [ 8, 0, 3, 1, 9, 10, 6, 4, 5, 2 ];
let maxNumber = Math.max(...arr);
let maxNumberIndex = arr.findIndex(el => el === maxNumber);
let newArr = [...arr.slice(0, maxNumberIndex), ...Array(arr.length - maxNumberIndex - 1).fill(0)];

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение, но я его принять не смогу, т.к. в нем есть ( Math.max(), findIndex(), slice()). Мне нужно научиться без специальных функций.

Comment: Понятно. Попробуйте то, что я написал в комментарии тогда

Answer (score 1):

Сделал вариант попроще, через два цикла.
Сделал еще копирование исходного массива, для того, чтобы не изменять исходный.

```js
const nums = [8, 0, 3, 1, 9, 10, 6, 4, 5, 2];

const changeArray = (arr) => {
  const _arr = [...arr];
  let maxIndex = 0;
  let max = arr[0];

  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] >= max) {
      max = arr[i];
      maxIndex = i;
    }
  }

  for (let i = maxIndex + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    _arr[i] = 0;
  }

  return _arr;
}



console.log(changeArray(nums));
```

Comment: Что означает эта запись: [...arr]?

Comment: Это оператор [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). По сути, раскрывает массив и помещает его значения в новый массив. Так как массив - это ссылочный тип данных, то при простом присвоении `const _arr = arr`, мы скопируем массив по ссылке и будем изменять исходный массив. Через оператор `spread`, мы берем все значения из массива `arr` и помещаем их внутрь нового массива.